# Why IF condition inside FOR loop not working?

Tags: apex, visualforce, string

I need to compare and remove two comma-separated String.

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="input_text">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Input}"/>
        <br></br>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Input2}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!getdata}" /> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!idString }"  />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex:**

```
public class input_text{
    public string input  {get;set;}
    public string input2  {get;set;}
    public Set<String> differences {get;set;}
    public String idString {get;set;}

    public void getdata(){
        List<String> lstString = input.split(',');
        List<String> lstexids = input2.split(',');
        for(string objId: lstString){   
            for (string j : lstexids){
                if (objId != j){
                    idString = idString + ','+objId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Output:** `null,1,2,3,4`

**Expected Output:** `1,2`

[image]

Comment: What input do you have?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy I have edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code and use `Set` to find non unique strings

```
public class input_text{
public string input  {get;set;}
public string input2  {get;set;}
public Set<String> differences {get;set;}
public String idString {get;set;}

public void getdata(){
    List<String> lstString = input.split(',');
    List<String> lstexids = input2.split(',');
    Set<String> uniqueLstexids = new Set<String>(lstexids);
    for(string objId: lstString){   
            if (!uniqueLstexids.contains(objId)){
                idString = idString + ','+objId;
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do Initialize `idString`

Answer (score 0):

to avoid nested for loops use `Set` collection to store split values from second input. Default value for class field of `String` is `null`. That is why setting result field to empty string is important, that will remove `null` from start of your result string.

```
public class input_text{
    public String input  {get;set;}
    public String input2  {get;set;}
    public Set<String> differences {get;set;}
    public String idString {get;set;}

    public input_text(){
        this.idString = '';
    }

    public void getdata(){
        List<String> lstString = input.split(',');
        Set<String> lstexids = new Set<String>(input2.split(','));
        for(String objId: lstString){   
            if(!lstexids.contains(objId)){
                append(objId);
            }
        }
    }

    private void append(String value){
        if(String.isNotBlank(idString)){
            idString +=',';
        }
        idString +=value;
    }
}
```